# How to map in Spring Boot where a Group has a one-to-one relationship to the User who created it, while also having one-to-many Users relationship?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, one-to-many, one-to-one

I am really new to using Spring Boot, and at the same time, this will be my first time trying to design something like this:

Groups will be created by an instance of User. In turn this instance of Group can have zero or more members.

[image: Groups will be created by an instance of User. In turn, this instance of Group can have zero or more members]

Or maybe it looks something like this, but I hope I don't have to create two separate table of users with identical fields:

[image]

At the same time, is it also possible to include the group_id as a foreign key relation of Users so that I can track what group an instance of User currently belongs to, so maybe like this?

[image]

I am kind of doing ok with simple @ManyToOne annotations but this is my first trying to do something like this, which, if I try to summarize is as follows:

1. A Group can be created by a User
2. A Group can have zero or many Users under it
3. A User instance has a relationship with which Group it currently belongs.
4. A User can only belong to one group, while, as in number 2, a Group can have multiple members.

How should I map this? In fact, how should my ERP even look?

Thank you.

Comment: Should the User also contain the information about the Group it created if any?

Comment: @JoãoDias, I'm still not sure, probably a one-to-one relationship also(?), but Groups can have multiple Users as its member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the User instance who created the Group:

```
@OneToOne
private User user;
```

For the User instances who are members of the Group:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany
private List<User> members;
```

For the inverse relation of a User instance to connect it to its Group:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private Group group;
```